# SAPUI5 - Refrech OData model

Tags: binding, model, refresh, sapui5

I'm working on a SAPUI5 Master Detail application with Odata model Two Way Binding.
When I click on a header element and enter data for its items and click submit, the entered data is still there.
Even if I click on another Header element, if I go back to the previous header element its data is still there.
I want the entire model to be completely refreshed on every click on a header element.
I tried SubmitChanges method, but it's not working ...

Answer (score -1):

**Check out the below sap archive**

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3649362

Comment: Link-only-answers are not useful. Please add some context.